# Mailcore2 on background

Tags: ios, iphone, mailcore2, mailcore

I'm using **Mailcore2** for an app that im developing by myself, and everything is perfect with Mailcore but now I'm trying to retrieve the emails when the user minimize the app (enter on background), I tried using background notifications but didn't work because time between the close and the first window to enter on my background function is too long.

So I tried to keep the idleOperation working when the user minimize the app but sometimes work perfect and sometime don't work at all.

Anyone have a solution to this?

I'm using Xcode and iOS 8.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time slice provided by iOS for background fetch is based on an algorithm unknown to the developers.
If you want to use the IMAP IDLE operation, then you will have to start inside the `performFetchWithCompletionHandler:` and make sure you are done before the app goes to sleep again i.e. anything from a few seconds to max 30 seconds.

I would suggest creating an IMAP session as soon as you enter background, poll IMAP for new changes, process and go to sleep ASAP. But again, iOS decides when and how long you get that time slice for background fetch.

UPDATED ANSWER:

If requirement is just getting the notifications for new emails, then just register for push notifications on your app and push them from your server or use services like [Pushwoosh](https://www.pushwoosh.com/).

Comment: thanks for your reply! but how the mail apps make to get the notification really fast? because they don't wait "the time" from iOS to retrieve the new stuff.

Comment: @santomegonzalo edited my answer. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: thanks again, i like your last idea, some guy from MailCore already told me send push notifications but to make that i need to have the credentials for every user (maybe i could save the tokens)... but i don't know if this is right because the user could think that this is not secure. What do you think?
Because if I used the push notification service I need to listen for every user every new email and google for example have e finite count of listeners to his box.

Comment: Push Notifications on iOS are routed through Apple's servers and secured with all the certificates you create for your app.  So I don't think you need to worry about the security. Even the server needs a key to trigger push notifications. Yes you have to save the device token for each device. 
Yes, Google is very strict about managing open connections to IMAP but it's ok if you manage them well. What you could do is, on your server manage just one open connection with IMAP and register for IMAP IDLE operation. When it responds with new emails, trigger a push notification to Apple's server.